# make d3.js datamap rotate by dragging with cursor

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, rotation, datamaps

i made [this map](http://unilogue.github.io/) using [datamaps](http://github.com/unilogue/datamaps) by [@markmarkoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134441/markmarkoh)

i love how it turned out but i wish i could get it to rotate when you drag it with the cursor, so you can see all of the continents. like the examples [here](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/johan/1392560).

here's a snippet of my code:

```js
//basic map config with custom fills, mercator projection
               
               var series = [
        ["USA",36.2],["GBR",7.4],["CAN",6.2],["DEU",5.7],["FRA", 4.1],["ESP",4.1],["ITA",3.3],["MEX",3.0],["AUS",2.5],["NLD",2.4],
        ["IND",2.1],["BRA",2.0],["GRC",1.4],["AUT",1.2],["ROU",1.2],["SRB",1.0],["COL",0.8],["POL",0.8],["ZAF",0.7],["SWE",0.7],
        ["DNK",0.6],["VEN",0.6],["JPN",0.6],["KOR",0.6],["BEL",0.5],["RUS",0.5],["PRT",0.5]
                            ];
                       
         var dataset = {};
            // We need to colorize every country based on "percent"
            // colors should be uniq for every value.
            // For this purpose we create palette(using min/max series-value)
            var onlyValues = series.map(function(obj){ return obj[1]; });
            var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, onlyValues),
                    maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, onlyValues);
            // create color palette function
            // color can be whatever you wish
            var paletteScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([minValue,maxValue])
                    .range(["rgb(0,0,0)","rgb(219,219,219)"]);  // color
            // fill dataset in appropriate format
            series.forEach(function(item){ //
                // item example value ["USA", 36.2]
                var iso = item[0],
                        value = item[1];
                dataset[iso] = { percent: value, fillColor: paletteScale(value) };
            });
              var map = new Datamap({
                scope: 'world',
                element: document.getElementById('world'),
                projection: 'orthographic',
                projectionConfig: {
                  rotation: [90,-30]
                },
                 fills: {defaultFill: 'rgba(30,30,30,0.1)'},
                data: dataset,
                geographyConfig: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(222,222,222,0.2)',
                    highlightBorderWidth: 1,
                    // don't change color on mouse hover
                    highlightFillColor: function(geo) {
                        return geo['fillColor'] || 'rgba(30,30,30,0.5)';
                    },
                    // only change border
                    highlightBorderColor: 'rgba(222,222,222,0.5)',
                    // show desired information in tooltip
                    popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
                        // don't show tooltip if country don't present in dataset
                        if (!data) { return ; }
                        // tooltip content
                        return ['',
                         '<div style="opacity:0.7;" class="hoverinfo">% of visitors in ' + geo.properties.name,
                                ': ' + data.percent,
                                ''].join('');        
                                
                    }
                }
            });
            
         
            //draw a legend for this map
            map.legend();
            
              map.graticule();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unilogue.github.io/js/map/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>

<div id="world" style="fill-opacity:0.7; height: 600px; width: 500px; margin-top:-100px;"></div>
```

edit: apparently the done callback lets you use events, i created this zoom/pan function as a test but how can i use this to rotate my map with d3.behavior.drag and euler angles?

```
var map = new Datamap({
                done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));
            function redraw() {
                datamap.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }
        },
```

edit 2: this looks like it could work! taken from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/wwymak/dcdd12937bd4643cd9b3).

i tried [copying](http://jsbin.com/rejuga/edit?html,output) it into a done callback but nothing happened, any ideas?

```
    var dragBehaviour = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', function(){
        var dx = d3.event.dx;
        var dy = d3.event.dy;

        var rotation = projection.rotate();
        var radius = projection.scale();
        var scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([-1 * radius, radius])
            .range([-90, 90]);
        var degX = scale(dx);
        var degY = scale(dy);
        rotation[0] += degX;
        rotation[1] -= degY;
        if (rotation[1] > 90)   rotation[1] = 90;
        if (rotation[1] < -90)  rotation[1] = -90;

        if (rotation[0] >= 180) rotation[0] -= 360;
        projection.rotate(rotation);
        redraw();
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var livemap;
scope.rotation = [97, -30];

function redraw() {
  d3.select("#map-wrapper").html('');
  init();
}// redraw


function init() {
  livemap = new Datamap({...})

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function() {
    var dx = d3.event.dx;
    var dy = d3.event.dy;

    var rotation = livemap.projection.rotate();
    var radius = livemap.projection.scale();
    var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-1 * radius, radius]).range([-90, 90]);
    var degX = scale(dx);
    var degY = scale(dy);
    rotation[0] += degX;
    rotation[1] -= degY;
    if (rotation[1] > 90) rotation[1] = 90;
    if (rotation[1] < -90) rotation[1] = -90;

    if (rotation[0] >= 180) rotation[0] -= 360;
    scope.rotation = rotation;
    redraw();
  })

 d3.select("#map-wrapper").select("svg").call(drag);

}// init
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! i've been waiting for over a year lol.. i'm having some trouble incorporating this into my code though, would you mind copy and pasting my snippet into your answer and adding your code into the javascript?

Comment: ah thanks a lot! i'm gonna make a pull request for the code on github, the developer should really incorporate this feature.

Comment: @optimus_max is there any way to auto rotate the map in addition to being draggable? I have tried to do it based on your code but was unsuccessful in doing so.